# How many subgroups of $D_4$ are isomophic to $V_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$D_4$= Dihedral Group, 
$V_4$= Klein Four Group.

All subgroups of $D_4$: {$1$}, 
{$1,a$}, 
{$1,ab$}, 
{$1,ab^2$}, 
{$1,ab^3$}, 
{$1,b^2$}, 
{$1,b,b^2,b^4$}, 
{$1,b^2,a,ab^2$}, 
{$1,b^2,ab,ab^3$},
$D_4$

Hmm I think only {$1,b^2,a,ab^2$} is, right?

Comment: There are two of them. There are a total of $5$ elements of order $2$. Any subgroup of order $4$ must contain the central one of these, and then it is a matter of picking another element and adding their product to get a subgroup like this.

Comment: So {$1,b^2,a,ab^2$} and {$1,b^2,ab,ab^3$}?

Comment: Correct, blondy. May be @Tobias could flesh the comment out to an answer?

Comment: Why is {$1,b^2$} the central element of order $2$ though?

Comment: That's not an element. It is a subgroup. It is also is the center of the group. Can you check that $b^2$ commutes with all the elements of $D_4$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Two reflections w.r.t. a pair of orthogonal lines will generate a copy of $V_4$.

Comment: Followig Tobias' comment is possibly the easiest way of proving that that all copies of $V_4$ are of this type. After all, $V_4$ contains three elements of order two, and they must commute with each other. Reflection w.r.t. non-orthogonal lines don't commute.